# WCF error "The size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota" when throwing FaultException

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to throw FaultException on server side of WCF application. I'm using DTO as payload for this exception. From some moment (for kind a big objects) I've started to receive "The size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota" exception on client side. All binding message size parameters and maxDepth set to big enouth value to get out of suspection.
Did anybody faced with this issue? It seems there are no solution in internet yet.
Setting

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" />
```

did not help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem was in "MaxFaultSize" parameter in ClientRuntime, default value is 65535, so you can't pass large payload in WCF's faults by default. To change this value, you should write custom EndpointBehavior like this:

```
public class MaxFaultSizeBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    private readonly int _size;

    public MaxFaultSizeBehavior(int size)
    {
        _size = size;
    }


    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {            
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {         
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {            
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MaxFaultSize = _size;
    }
}
```

and apply it to endpoint in **client** code when creating proxy:

```
_clientProxy.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MaxFaultSizeBehavior(1024000));
```

or, without proxy, just cast the client to add the behavior:

```
_client = new MyServiceClient();
((ClientBase<IMyService>) _client).Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MaxFaultSizeBehavior(1024000));
```

After that everything will be fine.
I've spent a lot of time searching answer, hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Interesting find. Good of you to post the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, this did work for me as well, definitely obscure and glad you found and posted it.  Just a heads up, one thing for me, in your section on "without proxy", I had to change the property from "behaviors" to "EndpointBehaviors", so something like this ..._client).Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add...,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the maxBufferSize? I think this is an example of maxing out all the settings, though I wouldn't copy it directly.

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyService" 
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                receiveTimeout="00:40:00" openTimeout="00:40:00" 
                closeTimeout="00:40:00" sendTimeout="00:40:00">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
                <security mode="None"/>
</binding>
```

Comment: Yes, all these parameters are big enough but still does not work. Finally I've found solution and will update my question soon

Comment: This will not help. There is a differnce between the sizes shown in this answer and the MaxFaultSize specifically.

Answer (score 0):

For those of us who are stuck in Visual Basic, here's the VB version of @ZlobnyiSerg 's excellent solution. **All credit goes to him.**

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Channels
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description
Imports System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher

Public Class MaxFaultSizeBehavior
    Implements IEndpointBehavior

    Private ReadOnly _size As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal size As Integer)
        _size = size
    End Sub

    Public Sub Validate(ByVal endpoint As ServiceEndpoint) Implements IEndpointBehavior.Validate
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddBindingParameters(ByVal endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, ByVal bindingParameters As BindingParameterCollection) Implements IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters
    End Sub

    Public Sub ApplyDispatchBehavior(ByVal endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, ByVal endpointDispatcher As EndpointDispatcher) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior
    End Sub

    Public Sub ApplyClientBehavior(ByVal endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, ByVal clientRuntime As ClientRuntime) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior
        clientRuntime.MaxFaultSize = _size
    End Sub
End Class
```